# Check that click isn't on grid elements

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a grid, there are: stackpanel, button and ~50% empty space.

I need to handle click only if it is not on button,stackpanel, only on empty space of grid.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example based on default template, with Grid named `LayoutRoot`.

```
private void LayoutRoot_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource == LayoutRoot)
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked on LayoutRoot!");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("You clicked on somewhere else!");
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" ... Tap="LayoutRoot_Tap">
```